# View Mathml Equations in browser

Tags: php, html, xml, xhtml, mathml

I hava a data which is stored in database using Wyris Editor for math equations.

```
<p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">  
     <mfrac><mn>2</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></math></p>
```

if i `echo` this data, i need to view it as equation as `2/2`..but the chrome browser just shows `22`.

How to view this equations?

Answer (score 3):

> If i echo
>
> ```
> <p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">  
>      <mfrac><mn>2</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></math></p>
> ```
>
> i need to view it as equation as `2/2` but the chrome browser just shows `22`.

To have MathML render properly the layout rendering engine used by your web browser need to support MathML. Gecko, used by Firefox, support it. WebKit, used by Chrome < 28, Safari and Epiphany, also support it **but** most of the time are disable at compilation time. Blink, used by Chrome > 28, does not support MathML at all. Internet Explorer and Edge also does not support MathML.

If you want to have MathML rendering across all web browsers you can use MathJax **and** you should check their API about adding new MathML elements.

Answer (score 1):

[MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) is the system may websites used. If you have firefox, they can display MathML natively.